# What happens when you translate a quotation?

Tags: translation

It feels to me like it is up to the author to choose what words will fit more properly. Does it become a paraphrase?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Suppboi*! I am not quite clear on what you are trying to achieve. Are you interested in [tag:academic-writing] and the usual practices of translating a quote for your reader? Your question reads a bit as if you are asking about a term that describes "translated quote", which would be off-topic on this site and maybe on-topic on our sister site [EnglishLanguage&Usage.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Could you [edit] your question to clarify what your goal is? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: BTW: For the moment I am voting to temporarily put this question on hold until it's been edited. If it gets put on hold the first [edit] from you will automatically send it to a special reopen review queue. It takes 5 community members with more than 3.000 reputation to put a question on hold and 5 other members to reopen a question. It's a normal process on the network to make sure that people answer the question you really have and that the question you have is on-topic for the site.

Comment: I'd have to VTC this. Other than the uncertainty I have with what is actually being asked, it can still be impossible to determine what to do with it when I understand. I mean, it depends on from which language, to which language. It depends on the translator. And it depends on a lot of factors (like local lingual gymnastics). And some words aren't even translatable. Like 'gezellig' in Dutch. There is no English word for it, and its use is so broad... So, uh. Yeah. Not sure how to even begin tackling the question.

Comment: you seem to know what the question is, just don't know what the answer is. Glad to know it only comes down to one person not getting it for it to be VTCd. Great

Comment: @Suppboi It takes five people not understanding what you're asking to VTC your question. Your question got 14 views. Out of them, 5 people weren't sure what you're asking, and some views might be by the same person (by you, for example). If you could clarify the question, it would help us provide a better answer, and the question would be reopened.

Comment: What's interesting about this question, and the responses, is the assumption that any translation will be an *accurate* translation. What if a quotation is translated by somebody who barely speaks the language it's translated into and it's completely botched, totally changing its meaning? It could be said to be a *terrible* translation. But, in another sense, it could—objectively—be seen as a paraphrase. Also, what if the languages don't have meanings that exactly translate? Who decides what is the "most" appropriate? One would think the author—but not if they don't speak the other language...

Comment: @Suppboi I like to let the OP know why I vote to close, so if you are interested, you can address the root cause and perhaps even better the question, so it can be voted open. If this is undesirable, please disregard my feedback.

Comment: But for clarity. What happens when you translate a quote? It is then (accurately or otherwise) written in another language. That's an answer, but is it the answer you want? Does it help you to understand? Is it being paraphrased? No, because that doesn't include translations. Can it be argued that it's being paraphrased? Yes, but it's inaccurate--translations almost always are, and that's the core of the problem. But, the problem here, is that while this all addresses your question, it doesn't answer it. And that's what I mean with 'unclear'.

Comment: Not understood. How do you want to translate it, and it also depends on the quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what context?

In a context of, for example, a newspaper, the quote is translated, and remains a quote. For example, today Israeli newspapers were all translating the statement of the Kensington Palace regarding Kate Middleton giving birth to a third child. It remained a quote, even though at least one newspaper managed to mistranslate "Her Royal Highness" as "Her Majesty".

In a literary work, if for instance a character quotes Shakespeare, a translator would usually quote the best known translation of Shakespeare into the target language, and add a footnote/endnote/something regarding who's the translator of Shakespeare. This has the added advantage of the readers in the target language likely being familiar with the quote as presented, which fits the intention of the author in quoting Shakespeare in the first place. If no translation is available (for example if the literary work being translated quotes someone less famous than Shakespeare, or if a crucial detail is lost in the existing translations), the translator would then translate the quote himself.

In no case does the quote become a paraphrase. It remains a translated quote.

Comment: Oh, so a "translated quote" is a thing, kind of in between quote and paraphrase?

Comment: @Suppboi If I understand your question correctly, then yes, of course. Have you ever heard "Sing, O Goddess, the rage of Achilles"? That's not a paraphrase of the opening line of the Iliad - that's a quote. Even though, obviously, the Iliad is in ancient Greek. So it's a translated quote. And because it's a translation, "Sing, O Muse, the anger of Achilles" is equally valid.